# Usar un array en una consulta sql con php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

lo que quiero lograr con esta consulta es que no me muestre los productos que ya están en la sucursal para esto tango un array de los productos de mi sucursal y lo quiero comprar con todos los productos que existen (que están en otra tabla) y los que si se encuentren en este array no los muestre solo los que no aparecen lo estoy haciendo de esta manera

```
                <form action="asignar_productos_sucursal.php" method="post">
                    <div class="card-body">
                    <input type="submit" name="cambiar" class="btn btn-primary position-realtive end-50" value="cambiar" >
                        <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>#</th>
                            <th>Producto</th>
                            <th>Familia</th>
                            <th>Existencias</th>
                            <th>Cantidad para Sucursal</th>
                            <th>Sucursal</th>
                            <th>Precio Por Sucursal</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <?php
                            $Productos_Sucursal = array();

                            $Productos_Sucursal_sql = "SELECT * FROM productos_sucursales WHERE sucursal = '$sucursal' ORDER BY id ASC";
                            $Sucursal_result = mysqli_query($con, $Productos_Sucursal_sql);
                            while ( $Productos_Sucursal_row = mysqli_fetch_array($Sucursal_result) ) { 
                            $Productos_Sucursal[] = $Productos_Sucursal_row['producto'] ;
                            
                            }
                            
                            $productos_sucrusales_existentes = implode(",",$Productos_Sucursal);
                            echo $productos_sucrusales_existentes;

                        include('my_function.php');
                        $currency = getCurrency();
                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM catalogo WHERE nombre NOT IN ('$productos_sucrusales_existentes') ORDER BY codigo ASC";
                        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
                        $i = 1;
                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                            echo "<tr>";
                            echo "<td>".$row['codigo']."</td>";
                            echo "<td> <input type='text' name='producto[]' value='".$row['nombre']."' readonly ></td>";
                            echo "<td> <input type='text' name='familia[]' value='".$row['departamento']."' readonly  ></td>";
                            echo "<td><input type='text' value=".$row['existencia']. " name='region' readonly  ></td>";
                            echo "<td><input type='text' value='$cantidad' placeholder='0' name='ExistenciasSucursal[]'  ></td>";
                            echo "<td><input type='text' value='$precio' placeholder='$0' name='PrecioSucursal[]' ></td>";
                            echo "<td><input type='text' value='$sucursal'  placeholder='' name='Sucursal[]' ></td>";
                            echo "</tr> ";
                        }
                        echo " </tbody>";
                        echo " </table>";
                        ?>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

mi array con los productos existentes en la sucursal es `$productos_sucrusales_existentes;` y solo para verlos le hago un echo, pero al momento de  querer hacer una consulta de sql con esta  variable no me muestra ningún resultado, y lo que quiero lograr es que solo me muestre los productos que no están en el array anterior

Comment: Puedes mostrar el echo de $productos_sucrusales_existentes, seguramente te faltarán las comillas que envuelven a cada elemento después de hacer el implode.

Answer (score 0):

Recorre el array `$productos_sucrusales_existentes`  con un `foreach` concatenas en un `string`  separados por  `,`

Luego utilizas la siguiente consulta `select * from tabla fron codigo in ("lista")`

codigo

```html
$productos = "",

foreach($productos_sucrusales_existentes as $k => $value){
 if($productos == "") $productos .= $value->codigo;
 else $productos .= ",".$value->codigo;
}

//creamos la consulta

 $query = "SELECT * from productos where codigo IN ($productos)";
```